# Is it possible to use the Zenoh Rust Api on embedded rust?

Tags: ros, rmw, zenoh

Since Zenoh will be a tier-1 RMW for ROS, I was thinking, "why not use Zenoh's rust API for microcontrollers ? "
As embedded rust is a thing and is widely used. I am aware of Zenoh Pico (C implementation) but .... Rust. This is just for implementation, nothing for production or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible at this stage. Zenoh currently requires libstd via some dependencies.
Porting Zenoh to no_std is something that have been discussed and an experiment was even started. But it's a big job and this experiment is currently on hold, due to other priorities (e.g. v1.0.0).

So for embedded Rust, I think the short term solution is to use Zenoh Pico via the Rust FFI.

Comment: Waiting hopefully :) 
Even the White House is endorsing rust, lol : https://www.whitehouse.gov/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/Final-ONCD-Technical-Report.pdf